# Array Error - Access violation reading location 0xffffffff

Tags: c++, sse, simd

I have previously used SIMD operators to improve the efficiency of my code, however I am now facing a new error which I cannot resolve. For this task, speed is paramount.

The size of the array will not be known until the data is imported, and may be very small (100 values) or enormous (10 million values). For the latter case, the code works fine, however I am encountering an error when I use fewer than 130036 array values.

Does anyone know what is causing this issue and how to resolve it?

I have attached the (tested) code involved, which will be used later in a more complicated function. The error occurs at "arg1List[i] = ..."

```
#include <iostream>
#include <xmmintrin.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>

void main()
{
    int j;
    const int loop = 130036;
    const int SIMDloop = (int)(loop/4);
    __m128 *arg1List = new __m128[SIMDloop];

    printf("sizeof(arg1List)= %d, alignof(Arg1List)= %d, pointer= %p", sizeof(arg1List), __alignof(arg1List), arg1List);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIMDloop; i++)
    {
        j = 4*i;
        arg1List[i] = _mm_set_ps((j+1)/100.0f, (j+2)/100.0f, (j+3)/100.0f, (j+4)/100.0f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try assigning the values to intermediaries like this report:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da/vclanguage/thread/05b765a2-ef2e-4e45-9229-266d7fe55c0f

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but `loop/4` will return an `int`, there is no need for that cast.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alignment is the reason.

> MOVAPS--Move Aligned Packed Single-Precision Floating-Point Values
>
> [...] The operand must be aligned on a 16-byte boundary or a general-protection exception (#GP) will be generated.

You can see the issue is gone as soon as you align your pointer:

```
__m128 *arg1List = new __m128[SIMDloop + 1];
arg1List = (__m128*) (((int) arg1List + 15) & ~15);
```

Comment: This works; thanks very much for the prompt reply. Though, why have you added 1 to the array size?

Comment: Because 0 to 15 leading bytes might be wasted with pointer re-alignment. To compensate for this, you need some spare bytes on the other end...

Comment: Ok, thanks. Out of curiosity, do you know why this was not an issue for the very large arrays?

Comment: My guess would be that when you allocate a larger array (BTW it appears to be 2+ MB) the heap allocator takes different code path and allocates some "new big page" to satisfy your request, which is already well-aligned. On a smaller block the alignment might be 8 or less because allocator does not seem to take care of 16-byte alignment.